Way to tell which of the XYZ axes are the vertical and horizontal ones based on elevation, azimuth and roll values
I am transforming my 3D plot into a 2D view using matplotlib. I do this by specifying specific elevation, azimuth and roll angles for the camera. I want to now be able to tell which of the axes (Positieve X, negative Z, negative Y, etc) are the horizontal and vertical axes shown on the 2D view of the plot. An example of this is

Elev: -90
Azim: 90
Roll: 0

This would result in the horizontal axis being -X and the vertical axis being +Y
I have tried creating functions which use simple logic based on the elevation, azimuth and roll angles but have not been able to succeed in doing so.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
